# IE sending empty HTTP request for iframe content

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic

IE intermittently sends a request missing nearly all the data. This is an intermittent problem, only sporadically encountered.

What might cause IE to send a request lacking nearly all the required values? Can anyone suggest a troubleshooting approach? Thanks!!

Our business application is an old classic asp application. Most users are still using Internet Explorer.

This problematic request is for the left menu, which is loaded in an iframe in Default.asp. Most of the time it works fine. But when it fails, the users see an empty space where the left menu should be displayed.

Tracing the network activity in the IE developer tools when it fails shows me that the request is lacking nearly all the data values expected. Here is the XML captured from such a request.

```
<entry>
  <pageref>0</pageref>
  <startedDateTime>2019-10-31T19:50:15.877-05:00</startedDateTime>
  <time>0</time>
  <request>
    <method/>
    <url>https://www.ourapplication.com/leftMenu.asp?Menu=Home</url>
    <httpVersion/>
    <cookies/>
    <headers/>
    <queryString>
      <param>
        <name>Menu</name>
        <value>Home</value>
      </param>
    </queryString>
    <headersSize>0</headersSize>
    <bodySize>0</bodySize>
  </request>
  <response>
    <cookies/>
    <headers/>
    <content>
      <size>0</size>
      <mimeType/>
    </content>
    <redirectionURL/>
    <headersSize>0</headersSize>
    <bodySize>0</bodySize>
  </response>
  <cache/>
  <timings>
    <send>0</send>
    <wait>-1</wait>
    <receive>-1</receive>
  </timings>
</entry>
```

When it works, the XML does contain all the data needed in the request and a valid response is received.

```
<entry>
  <pageref>0</pageref>
  <startedDateTime>2019-10-31T20:18:15.495-05:00</startedDateTime>
  <time>94</time>
  <request>
    <method>GET</method>
    <url>https://www.ourapplication.com/leftMenu.asp?Menu=Home</url>
    <httpVersion>HTTP/1.1</httpVersion>
    <cookies>
      <cookie>
        <name>Secure</name>
        <value>DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709</value>
      </cookie>
      <cookie>
        <name>Secure</name>
        <value>DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709</value>
      </cookie>
      <cookie>
        <name>ASPSESSIONIDQAGVVACT</name>
        <value>CMPFHDEBGFIGPGBFLEACHIII</value>
      </cookie>
    </cookies>
    <headers>
      <header>
        <name>Accept</name>
        <value>text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Referer</name>
        <value>https://www.ourapplication.com/</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Accept-Language</name>
        <value>en-US</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>User-Agent</name>
        <value>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Accept-Encoding</name>
        <value>gzip, deflate</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Host</name>
        <value>www.ourapplication.com</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>DNT</name>
        <value>1</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Connection</name>
        <value>Keep-Alive</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Cache-Control</name>
        <value>no-cache</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Cookie</name>
        <value>Secure=DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709; Secure=DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709; ASPSESSIONIDQAGVVACT=CMPFHDEBGFIGPGBFLEACHIII</value>
      </header>
    </headers>
    <queryString>
      <param>
        <name>Menu</name>
        <value>Home</value>
      </param>
    </queryString>
    <headersSize>540</headersSize>
    <bodySize>0</bodySize>
  </request>
  <response>
    <status>200</status>
    <statusText>OK</statusText>
    <httpVersion>HTTP/1.1</httpVersion>
    <cookies/>
    <headers>
      <header>
        <name>Cache-Control</name>
        <value>private</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Content-Type</name>
        <value>text/html</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Expires</name>
        <value>Thu, 31 Oct 2019 20:18:57 GMT</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Server</name>
        <value>Microsoft-IIS/8.5</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>X-Powered-By</name>
        <value>ASP.NET</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Date</name>
        <value>Thu, 31 Oct 2019 20:18:57 GMT</value>
      </header>
      <header>
        <name>Content-Length</name>
        <value>1,397</value>
      </header>
    </headers>
    <content>
      <size>3747</size>
      <mimeType>text/html</mimeType>
      <text>
      ...html content removed for brevity
      </text>
    </content>
    <redirectionURL/>
    <headersSize>195</headersSize>
    <bodySize>3747</bodySize>
  </response>
  <cache/>
  <timings>
    <send>0</send>
    <wait>94</wait>
    <receive>0</receive>
  </timings>
</entry>
```

Comment: Which version of IE browser you are using for making this test? If you are using any older version than it is recommended to move to IE 11 version. Did you notice any error message in console? Does this error start occurring after any recent change or modification? If there is any example or sample code to reproduce the issue than please try to provide it. We will try to test it on our side.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! We are using IE 11 on Windows 7 for most users. No errors in the console whatsoever. This is such an intermittent issue. I cannot reliably reproduce it. I cannot reproduce it at all on Chrome or other browsers - only IE 11. And it seems that only certain users see this problem more frequently than others using the same browser and operating system. Any ideas on a troubleshooting approach?

Comment: Can you provide any sample or steps so that we can try to test and see the results? It will help to understand the issue in better way. Without reproducing it, it will be complicated to make any comment about the cause.

Comment: I agree. Reproducing the issue is the best way to begin troubleshooting. Unfortunately, we have been unable to reproduce it other than in the production environment...and then only intermittently. The loading steps start with Default.asp which contains a frameset with an iframe that loads leftMenu.asp. This is within the context of an application that enforces user security with sessions and interacts with a database layer. Thank you for trying to help me. I just don't have a reasonable  or reliable way for you to reproduce the issue in your environment.

Comment: You can try to check the settings of an IE browser for the users who are facing the issue frequently and compare it with the settings of IE users who does not have this issue. Also try to check and verify that both kind of users are using similar Windows update. If there settings are different then make it similar for testing purpose. It may give some idea and can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Deepak-MSFT I appreciate your help!

Comment: Let us know about your testing results. We will try to provide further suggestions if needed.

Comment: @MikeZ, if your XML formed as result of database query - check for type of field `URL` - I suspect it's of type (n)next or (n)varchar(max). Then You should convert that field to varchar(8000) or nvarchar(4000)